# Matplotlib y-scale setting - ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to transform the scale of y-axis to log by `plt.yscale('log')`

```
def gen_spectrograms(wav):

    fs, x = scipy.io.wavfile.read(wav) # read audio file as np array
    spec, freqs, _, _= plt.specgram(x, Fs=fs, NFFT=2048, noverlap=1900, mode='default')
    plt.close('all')
    gc.collect()

    spec_ = spec[:600, :]
    spec_ = spec_[::-1]
    spec_ = cv2.resize(spec_, dsize=(128, 256), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

    return spec_


spec = gen_spectrograms(p)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.imshow(spec)
```

The whole error report:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/Terry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    335                 pass
    336             else:
--> 337                 return printer(obj)
    338             # Finally look for special method names
    339             method = _safe_get_formatter_method(obj, self.print_method)

/Users/Terry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
    205 
    206     if 'png' in formats:
--> 207         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    208     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    209         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

/Users/Terry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    115 
    116     bytes_io = BytesIO()
--> 117     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    118     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    119     if fmt == 'svg':

/Users/Terry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
   2230                 orientation=orientation,
   2231                 bbox_inches_restore=_bbox_inches_restore,
-> 2232                 **kwargs)
   2233         finally:
   2234             if bbox_inches and restore_bbox:

/Users/Terry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
    525 
    526     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
--> 527         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    528         renderer = self.get_renderer()
    529         original_dpi = renderer.dpi

/Users/Terry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py in draw(self)
    467         if __debug__: verbose.report('FigureCanvasAgg.draw', 'debug-annoying')
    468 
--> 469         self.renderer = self.get_renderer(cleared=True)
    470         # acquire a lock on the shared font cache
    471         RendererAgg.lock.acquire()

/Users/Terry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py in get_renderer(self, cleared)
    484 
    485         if need_new_renderer:
--> 486             self.renderer = RendererAgg(w, h, self.figure.dpi)
    487             self._lastKey = key
    488         elif cleared:

/Users/Terry/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py in __init__(self, width, height, dpi)
     91         self.height = height
     92         if __debug__: verbose.report('RendererAgg.__init__ width=%s, height=%s'%(width, height), 'debug-annoying')
---> 93         self._renderer = _RendererAgg(int(width), int(height), dpi, debug=False)
     94         self._filter_renderers = []
     95 

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

I suspect the error occurred because of some pixel values are too small? Please give me some suggestions. Thank you.

---

April-23 11:20 Update

I've simplified my code to:

```
wav = 'audio.wav'
fs, x = scipy.io.wavfile.read(wav) # read audio file as np array
spec, _, _, _ = plt.specgram(x, Fs=fs, NFFT=2048, noverlap=1900, mode='default')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.imshow(spec)
```

And the error report is:

```
/home/gty/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py:3477: UserWarning: Attempted to set non-positive ylimits for log-scale axis; invalid limits will be ignored.
  'Attempted to set non-positive ylimits for log-scale axis; '
```

```
<matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x7f6dd803ada0>
```

```
/home/gty/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py:1579: UserWarning: aspect is not supported for Axes with xscale=linear, yscale=log
  'yscale=%s' % (xscale, yscale))
/home/gty/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py:2745: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  y_scale = 1.0 / inh
posx and posy should be finite values
posx and posy should be finite values
posx and posy should be finite values
posx and posy should be finite values
posx and posy should be finite values
posx and posy should be finite values
posx and posy should be finite values
posx and posy should be finite values
posx and posy should be finite values
posx and posy should be finite values
posx and posy should be finite values
posx and posy should be finite values
posx and posy should be finite values
posx and posy should be finite values
/home/gty/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py:416: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  return points[1, 0] - points[0, 0]
```

Comment: You are getting the error in print_figure which you don’t have in your code.  Can you post a complete self contained reproduction of the error?

Comment: I think there's a better way to go about this. Check out [this blog post by Christian Hill](https://scipython.com/blog/hidden-images-in-spectrograms/) which uses a log scale on the frequency axis. I would definitely try to keep `cv2` out of there.

Comment: @JodyKlymak Sorry I don't fully understand your comment, please see my latest update.

Comment: @kwinkunks I tried this, but didn't work. please see the edited post above

Comment: Previously you reported about an error. Now you report about a warning. The warning essentially tells you that your very first image cell, which would normally range from -0.5 to 0.5 cannot be displayed on a logarithmic scale, because negative logarithms are not defined. The rest of the image should show just fine, right?